# Is there a standard func that takes a dict and a list of keys and returns the list of corresponding vals?

Tags: clojure

I'm looking for something similar to [select-keys](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/select-keys):

```
(desired-fn {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :d 4} [:a :d])
;= [1 4]

;; N.B. the order of the keys in the argument seq is preserved
(= (desired-fn (array-map :a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :d 4)
               [:b :c])
   (desired-fn (array-map :d 4, :c 3, :a 1, :b 2)
               [:b :c]))
;= true
```

It's not particularly hard to implement, though I haven't tried to come up with a good name yet:

```
(defn select-values-corresponding-to-keys [m ks]
  (for [k ks]
    (get m k)))
```

Am I ignorant of a standard function that meets precisely this need? If not, do other languages —e.g., Python, Ruby, Haskell— have a name for this function?

Answer (score 13):

Maps are functions which operate on their keys:

```
({:a 1, :b 2} :a)
;=> 1

(map {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :d 4} [:a :d])
;=> (1 4)

(= (map (array-map :a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :d 4)
           [:b :c])
   (map (array-map :d 4, :c 3, :a 1, :b 2)
           [:b :c]))
;=> true
```

If you want the result as a vector, just use `vec` or `into [] ...`, or replace `map` with `mapv`.

Comment: in other words (def desired-fn mapv)

Comment: You're absolutely right that an elegant feature of Clojure means that the function is trivial to implement. (when I had a need for `select-values-corresponding-to-keys`, I actually settled on doing something very similar.)

Answer (score 4):

`map` is the function you are looking for:

```
(map {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} [:a :c])
=> (1 3)
```

This works because the hashmap itself works as a function (i.e. implements `clojure.lang.IFn`) that returns the value for any key that it is given.

Answer (score 4):

```
user=> ((juxt :a :c) {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
[1 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Keywords are themselves functions (they implement `IFn`) and they can *look themselves* into a map and return the value so one option would be to use `juxt`:

```
(def keys-to-vals (juxt :b :c))
(= (keys-to-vals {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :d 4})
   (keys-to-vals {:d 4, :c 3, :a 1, :b 2}))
```

So basically your desired fn now becomes:

```
(defn select-vals [map keys] ((apply juxt keys) map))
```

Answer (score 1):

Jay Fields explores this function and a couple other related ones in an insightful blog post @ http://blog.jayfields.com/2011/01/clojure-select-keys-select-values-and.html.

(I found that by accident just a few minutes ago when I searched for "select-keys".)

I'd still like to know if there's a "canonical" implementation somewhere, so I'm leaving the question as open.

Comment: As is probably clear, there is a 'canonical' implementation and it is `map`; any of the above `map` answers are correct. `map` used in that way is a synonyn to what Jay's article calls `select-values`.